vs code: Error while fetching extensions. Failed to fetch
When I try to search some extensions in vs code marketplace list of exts not appears, when I met this problem the load was infinite without some errors, after I start to solve this, the error appears.
My OS is Ubuntu 24.04.1
vscode version  is 1.93.1 x64
Problems starts when I update vs code, when I open vsc after upd .NET extensions show me errors in panel in bottom, and my font not work anymore.
For first I try to disable and remove .NET extensions, does not work, after I remove font, I remove all from user config.json and workspace config.json, still not work. I fully reinstall vs code using guids, I clear hidden dir and used this guid for installation https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux. The problem still appears. I don't know where to look in vs code to understand what is this problem.
One thing when I installing vs code in output in terminal on button I got this warning:

Download is performed unsandboxed as root as file '/home/myme/Documents/code_1.92.2-1723660989_amd64.deb' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)

I don't remember whether I got this warning when i install it for first time or not. As I has read I can ignore this warning.
Else I tried to install previous version 1.92.2, and I have same problem. And I tried to install it from Document directory.
What can I try next?

I got handle it, it was so dumb from my side to think this is pc problem.
So if you live in rassia or some place like this, you have to use proxy.

open vs code, open command platte (i used Ctrl + Shift + P) write Preferences: Open Settings (JSON), i choose user.
add to this file these:
"http.proxySupport": "on",
"http.proxy": "http://your-proxy-address:port",
"http.proxyAuthorization": "Basic <base64-encoded-username-password>",
save, restart.

OR use vpn
